# ¿Cómo comprobar que el servidor SQL Server existe?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

Quiero comprobar si el nombre del servidor al que deseo conectarme esta disponible, antes de crear la cadena de conexión, ya que si uso `SqlConnection` y trato de conectarme a un servidor no accesible, esto lleva mucho tiempo. Esto no tiene nada que ver con el tiempo de espera de la conexión.

Para lograr esto he usado la clase [**System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) para enumerar todas las instancias disponibles de SQL Server en la red local.

Algo asi (Codigo C#):

```
public void InstanciasLocales()
{
     using (DataTable instancias_sql = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources())
     {
          foreach (DataRow instancia in instancias_sql.Rows)
          {
               string nombre_servidor;
               string nombre_instancia = instancia["InstanceName"].ToString();
               string mensaje;

               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre_instancia))
                   nombre_servidor = instancia["ServerName"] + "\\" + instancia["InstanceName"].ToString();
               else
                   nombre_servidor = instancia["ServerName"].ToString();

               mensaje = string.Format("Nombre Servidor: {0} \nVersion: {1}", nombre_servidor, instancia["Version"]);
               MessageBox.Show("SQL SERVER\n\n" + mensaje, "INSTANCIAS SQL SERVER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
          }
     }
}
```

Aquí en el ciclo `forech` podría validar si existe el servidor al que deseo conectarme:

```
if (nombre_servidor.Equals("Nombre del servidor que busco"))
```

Pero de igual forma para obtener el listado de todas las instancias disponible se tarda un tiempo, que va a depender de la cantidad de servidores que encuentre en la red.

**¿Existe alguna forma de obtener solo el servidor que deseo y no un listado completo?**. Algo similar a lo que hace `GetDataSources` pero que sea condiciondo con un `Where servername = "el servidor"` de modo que solo intente localizar en la red.

Comment: Hice esta prueba y me funciono: **System.Data.DataRow dr = ((System.Data.DataTable)System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()).Select().Where(x => x["ServerName"].ToString() == "NOMBRE DEL SERVIDOR").First();**

Comment: @VictorPerdomo gracias, si funciona, sin embargo de igual modo se está cargando la lista completa de servidores `GetDataSources()` aunque todo mi código se resume en esa linea de código que me propone, pero igual se tomará el tiempo de cargar la lista, ese es el enfoque que busco con la condición `Where` pero sin tener que cargar el montón de servidores que puede contener la red.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo y en caso de que otro usuario quiera usarlo de la forma que usted propone, recomiendo usar `FirstOrDefault()` el cuál devolverá nulo en caso de no tener elementos. En lugar de  usar `First()` ya que si el servidor no existe se arrojará una excepción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de haber buscado encontré una solución, recuperando las instancias locales del registro de Windows. Buscándolas en `WOW64` y `WOW6432`.

- WOW64: para obtener SQL Server 2008 (64 bits)
- WOW6432: para SQL Server Express (32 bits)

  ```
  /// <summary>
  ///  obtener los nombres de instancias del servidor sql local del registro de Windows WOW64 y WOW3264
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>Una lista de nombres de instancia de servidor sql local</returns>
  public IList<string> GetLocalSqlServerInstanceNames()
  {
      RegistryValueDataReader registryValueDataReader = new RegistryValueDataReader();

      string[] instances64Bit = registryValueDataReader.ReadRegistryValueData(RegistryHive.Wow64,
                                                                              Registry.LocalMachine,
                                                                              @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server",
                                                                              "InstalledInstances");

      string[] instances32Bit = registryValueDataReader.ReadRegistryValueData(RegistryHive.Wow6432,
                                                                              Registry.LocalMachine,
                                                                              @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server",
                                                                              "InstalledInstances");

      IList<string> localInstanceNames = new List<string>(instances64Bit);

      localInstanceNames = localInstanceNames.Union(instances32Bit).ToList();

      return localInstanceNames;
  }
  ```

---

```
    public enum RegistryHive
    {
        Wow64,
        Wow6432
    }

    public class RegistryValueDataReader
    {
        private static readonly int KEY_WOW64_32KEY = 0x200;
        private static readonly int KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x100;

        private static readonly UIntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = (UIntPtr)0x80000002;

        private static readonly int KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 0x1;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "RegOpenKeyEx")]
        static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
                    UIntPtr hKey,
                    string subKey,
                    uint options,
                    int sam,
                    out IntPtr phkResult);


        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int RegQueryValueEx(
                    IntPtr hKey,
                    string lpValueName,
                    int lpReserved,
                    out uint lpType,
                    IntPtr lpData,
                    ref uint lpcbData);

        private static int GetRegistryHiveKey(RegistryHive registryHive)
        {
            return registryHive == RegistryHive.Wow64 ? KEY_WOW64_64KEY : KEY_WOW64_32KEY;
        }

        private static UIntPtr GetRegistryKeyUIntPtr(RegistryKey registry)
        {
            if (registry == Registry.LocalMachine)
            {
                return HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
            }

            return UIntPtr.Zero;
        }

        public string[] ReadRegistryValueData(RegistryHive registryHive, RegistryKey registryKey, string subKey, string valueName)
        {
            string[] instanceNames = new string[0];

            int key = GetRegistryHiveKey(registryHive);
            UIntPtr registryKeyUIntPtr = GetRegistryKeyUIntPtr(registryKey);

            IntPtr hResult;

            int res = RegOpenKeyEx(registryKeyUIntPtr, subKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | key, out hResult);

            if (res == 0)
            {
                uint type;
                uint dataLen = 0;

                RegQueryValueEx(hResult, valueName, 0, out type, IntPtr.Zero, ref dataLen);

                byte[] databuff = new byte[dataLen];
                byte[] temp = new byte[dataLen];

                List<String> values = new List<string>();

                GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(databuff, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                try
                {
                    RegQueryValueEx(hResult, valueName, 0, out type, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), ref dataLen);
                }
                finally
                {
                    handle.Free();
                }

                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;

                while (i < databuff.Length)
                {
                    if (databuff[i] == '\0')
                    {
                        j = 0;
                        string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(temp).Trim('\0');

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                        {
                            values.Add(str);
                        }

                        temp = new byte[dataLen];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp[j++] = databuff[i];
                    }

                    ++i;
                }

                instanceNames = new string[values.Count];
                values.CopyTo(instanceNames);
            }

            return instanceNames;
        }
    }
```

Y si desea combinar el nombre del equipo para completar el nombre de la instancia, se podría obtener de esta manera en WindowsForms:

```
Environment.MachineName //Nombre del Equipo
SystemInformation.ComputerName //Nombre del Equipo
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar realizar una conexión rápida a la base como comprobación de que es accesible, es decir un Open con un timeout muy corto, 1~2 segundos.

Connection Timeout=**ENTERO EN SEGUNDOS**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("CADENA CONEXION; Connection Timeout=2");
conn.Open();
```

De esta forma no se quedará colgado como mencionas y sabrás si te puedes conectar o no.

Comment: Gracias, pero no es lo que busco, si se fija en los detalles de mi pregunta digo _comprobar el servidor antes de crear la **cadena de conexón** y antes de usar `SqlConnection`_

Comment: Está bien lo que buscas pero considero que es más complejo porque si se cae un servidor cómo actualizarías tu lista? o vas a revisarla antes de hacer cada cosa? al final sería como lo que propongo.

Comment: _si se cae un servidor cómo actualizarías tu lista?_ Actualizar que lista? creo que no ha entendido correctamente mi pregunta, de ese modo obtengo la lista de servidores, pero NO me interesa la lista, me interesa buscar solo uno, y si el servidor no existe, pues es tan sencillo como mostrar un aviso al usuario de que el servidor no esta accesible.